# How to query transaction details by using the transaction hash on polkadot by using python

Tags: polkadot, transactions, api, python

Is there something equivalent to  [`w3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction), for Substrate based chains using python?

Comment: Could you select an answer if any one of them answers your question?

Answer (score 3):

Transaction hashes have a different meaning in Polkadot than in Ethereum.
Ethereum TX hashes uniquely identify a transaction in a Block.
TX hashes in Polkadot are not necessarily unique. They are calculated from the function name and its argument values. So they identify a Transaction regardless of whether it's inside a block or not.
Many Polkadot Transactions will therefore share the *same* hash.

Transactions in Polkadot are identified by their block-number and the index that they have in that block.  For example [#11831228-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/11831228-2) is transaction 2 in Block 11831228.

Have a look at [py-substrate-interface](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#method-1-access-serialized-value) which has an example on how to list the extrinsics of a block.

Comment: There is indeed as far as I know no index available to lookup extrinsic by its hash in the Substrate RPC. You will need a third-party indexer for that